# Recursive comment system in django

Tags: python, django

I have a comment system for my website and I pass all the comments with the relevant post but when I loop through the comments and show each comment it's children it shows the children after it as independent comments.

```
{% load custom_tags %}
{% for comment in page_obj %}
<div class="comments">
  <h6>
    <a href="{% url 'main:creator' comment.publisher.id %}">
      {{comment.publisher.name}}
    </a>
  </h6>    
  <span>{{ comment.created_on}}</span>
  <div>
    {{comment.text}}
    <br>
  </div>
  {% if comment.children %}
  <ul style="margin-right: 5%;">
    {% include "post/comment.html" with page_obj=comment.children %}
  </ul>
  {% endif %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Share your model that we can see how posts are saved and linked together.

Answer (score 0):

You confused `margin-right` and `margin-left`. Setting `margin-right: 5%;` wouldn't add the right margin which wouldn't move the child comments. You need to replace `margin-right: 5%;` with `margin-left: 5%;`.

The other possibility is related to peculiarities of parent `div`. `5%` might not works in some situations. You can try to replace it with something like `50px` in case the previous option doesn't works.